# Variable assignment using dynamic object restructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a local state object that looks will look like this:

```
state:{
   pickup:{
      blah: stuff
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
state:{
   dropoff:{
      blah: stuff
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is grab *either* the pickup or dropoff object and set it to some other variable.

This is being done in a function that is passing in whichever type we are attempting to pull off.

**tl;dr** How can I do something like `const location = this.state.[locationType]` where `locationType` is passed into my function.

Comment: If `locationType` is a string, just drop the `.` and do `const location = this.state[locationType]`

Comment: you want a dynamic key in state? whyyyyyyy

Comment: @Ted sorry, maybe I was unclear. Both `pickup` and `dropoff` exist in state, I am just attempting to access a particular one that is designated by a particular component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Nick Tower's comment,

`const location = this.state[locationType]`

produced the desired result.